# Is it allowed (aka a "good idea") to pass a CDI "Instance<>"-instance to a ManagedExecutorService Runnable?

Tags: java, multithreading, cdi

I have a stateless session bean and the only reason i use an EJB is because i want to utilize the @Schedule annotation, so the container can frequently trigger my code.

The code itself uses an Instance<> to dynamically inject CDI beans (think of them as "workers")

```
@Inject @Any 
private Instance<OutboundMessageProcessor> outboundMessageProcessorFactory;
```

those OutboundMessageProcessor beans implement the Runnable interface and will be submitted to a ManagedExecutorService for parallel execution:

```
 // create a processor 
 OutboundMessageProcessor outboundMessageProcessor = outboundMessageProcessorFactory.get();

 // and run it 
 Future<?> future = managedExecutorService.submit( outboundMessageProcessor );
```

Unfortunately this leads to a memory leak. My understanding is that this happens because the OutboundMessageProcessor beans have a @Dependent scope and so they live as long as the object that injected them lives, which is the EJB in this case, and the EJB is pooled by the container, so it "never" dies and the OutboundMessageProcessor instances never get removed by the garbage collector.

The solution is to call outboundMessageProcessorFactory.destroy() with the injected bean as parameter after you're done with it. But the problem is that I can't wait in the EJB for the Future to finish. That would defeat the purpose of running it in a new Thread in the first place.

So my idea was, what if i pass the outboundMessageProcessorFactory instance to the outboundMessageProcessor? After getting the outboundMessageProcessor instance with outboundMessageProcessorFactory.get() I could just call a .setFactory() method and pass it along. Then whenever the Runnable is done it could destroy itself at the end of its run() method, using the passed along factory and itself as a parameter to the destroy method.

So my question is, if this is a "good idea"? Will it work at all or will i run into problems because the outboundMessageProcessorFactory instance doesn't really "belong" into the "scope" of the other Thread?

And if this is a bad idea, how could i approach this memory leak otherwise?

EDIT: while i really liked the idea provided by Nikos in the comments, by the time i read it, i already went with another solution. Which is to cache/pool the processor instances and reuse them. Apart from avoiding the memory leak this has the added benefit of giving a slight performance gain. and in my case the number of distinct processors that needed to be cached/pooled was small, so the memory overhead was insignificant.

Comment: Hi, I believe passing the `Instance` to the `OutboundMessageProcessor`, so that the latter can destroy itself is a bad idea because it blurs the responsibilities of each component. Why don't you pass a `Runnable` to the managed executor service that knows how to destroy the processor? Like: `managedExecutorService.submit(() -> { try { outboundMessageProcessor.run(); } finally { outboundMessageProcessorFactory.destroy(outboundMessageProcessor); });`. This way the EJB is responsible for the lifecycle of the processor, while the processor is responsible for doing its thing, whatever it is.

Comment: thats a neat way of providing the Runnable to the managed executor service while keeping control over what to do when it ends. very neat idea, thank you!